# Unable to construct a vector<std::unique<...>> using an initialiser list

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr, initializer-list

I'm trying to initailise a vector of unique_ptr using an initialiser list and it fails with a compiler error.  Which seems odd as it looks similar to a number of examples that I've seen.

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::string>> v{
    std::unique_ptr<std::string>{new std::string{"foo"}}
};
```

Fails with a compiler error.

```
.../memory:1645:31: error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::basic_string<char> > >'
        ::new((void*)__p) _Up(_VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
...
...47: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::vector<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::basic_string<char> > >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::basic_string<char> > > > >::vector' requested here
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::string>> v{
                                          ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) has no copy constructor.  You create an instance and then ask the [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to copy that instance during initialisation.

```
error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::basic_string<char>, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::basic_string<char> > >'
        ::new((void*)__p) _Up(_VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
```

> The class satisfies the requirements of MoveConstructible and
>   MoveAssignable, but not the requirements of either CopyConstructible
>   or CopyAssignable.

The following works with the new [emplace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace) calls. However fails to utilise initialisation lists.

```
std::vector< std::unique_ptr< std::string > > v;
v.emplace_back( new std::string{ "foo" } );
```

See [using unique_ptr with standard library containers](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/06/20/c11-using-unique_ptr-with-standard-library-containers) for further reading.

Comment: Just be aware that `emplace_back` can be used to add multiple elements, which is not exception safe when you use multiple `new` expressions.

Comment: @Jens Even this `emplace_back` is not safe. If the vector reallocates, and the reallocation throws, the pointer is leaked.